# Чи існують для української мови сервіси перевірки граматики та покращення стілистики?

Tags: software

Перевірка правопису та граматики у Microsoft word, звісно, працює, але іноді її недостатньо.

Чи є для української мови сервіси перевірки граматики та покращення стілистики на кшталт [Gramarly](http://grammarly.com)  або [Главред](https://glvrd.ru/)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**LanguageTool** здатен перевіряти українські тексти. Перевіряти можна:

- прямо на [сайті LanguageTool](https://www.languagetool.org/);
- на [сайті R2U](https://r2u.org.ua/check);
- на [сайті «Мова — ДНК нації»](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/perevirka-tekstu);
- встановивши плагін для браузера (Mozilla Firefox, Google Chrome);
- встановивши плагін для офісного пакета (Microsoft Office, LibreOffice/OpenOffice, Google Docs);
- встановивши версію для офлайн-використання на персональний комп'ютер (під будь-яку ОС);
- встановивши плагін для смартфона під Android;
- тощо.

Звісно, він не ідеальний і помічає не всі помилки. З іншого боку, в деяких  випадках він, на мою думку, навпаки, надто суворий і відмічає як помилки слова, які є в серйозних словниках або статус яких неочевидний.

Answer (score 4):

Також існує [**OnlineCorrector**](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua), але з нахилом до плати.